# How to verify whether google search results consist of a specific text using selenium?

Tags: selenium, automation

I want to verify if the google search results contain the specific text or not.
Following is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("setting the driver path");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",   "C:\\Users\\Arushi\\Desktop\\Arushi\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    textbox.sendKeys("stack");

    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.name("btnG"));
    button.click();

    String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue("Text not found!", bodyText.contains("stackoverflow.com"));
```

But the above code does not give correct result. The getText() method gets the body text of the page "google.com" instead of the page loaded after performing the search.

I want to know 2 things:
 1. Why does getText() above is picking up the body text from google.com
 2. What is the correct way to search for the specific text in the google search results.

Note: I also tried driver.getPageSource().contains() method but even that's not giving the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

I would attack this by identifying the exact elements that represent search results on the DOM, then loop over each instance of a search result to validate the text for my search term.  Simply searching the full page for some text opens up some opportunities for inaccurate results.

By looking at the DOM of a google search result page, we can see that each of the search results live in a node with class `.rc`.  Children of that node, with classes `.r` and `.s` represent the result name and description, respectively.

I'll assume for this example that you'd like to check the search result names for your search term, but you should be able to easily refactor the code below to your specific needs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // First, let's declare our search term
    private String searchTerm = "Selenium";

    // Then, let's start our WebDriver and navigate to google
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // Next, we'll execute the search
    WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchField.sendKeys(searchTerm);
    WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));
    searchButton.click();

    // Now, let's gather our search results
    List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".r"));

    // Finally, we'll loop over the list to verify each result link contains our term
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        Assert.assertTrue(results.get(i).getText().contains(searchTerm), "Search result validation failed at instance [ + i + ].");
    }
}
```

You may need to add any appropriate waits.  This can also be further tweaked to ensure each result will be evaluated before a final pass/fail with a full output of each individual result that did not match the term, but I'll leave that to you to implement.  Hopefully this will be a good start for you.